# Is the sentence "I would be going on a vacation." grammatically correct?

Tags: conditionals

Is this sentence correct?

> "I would be going on a vacation."

I tried searching for similar sentences online and came across Conditional tenses. But from what I understand they have two clause - the 'if' and the main clause.

So if the sentence was,

> "If I completed my work, I would be going on vacation."

it probably would have been correct. But I am unsure if **"I would be going on vacation"** is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by tense? Please edit your question to say what you mean. There are only two tenses in English: past and nonpast. Although *would* is in origin the backshifted version of *will*, it is not thought of as being in the past tense these days. Modals have no tense, and so neither do the three verbs in your sentence. If by tense you mean dozens and dozens of multi-word constructions that are not morphological inflections of a single word, then it is unlikely that we will be able to answer whatever you are expecting here. You might try our sister site for [ell.se] instead.

Comment: Without seeing more surrounding context, it is difficult to say.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by surrounding context? 

I basically have a list of sentences that I have to classify as 'present', 'past' and 'future' programmatically. All the sentences are independent of each other and one of the sentences is of the form - "I would be going on a vacation." I am not sure if the sentence is right.

Comment: *“I was so excited by the news. Finally, I would be going on vacation!”*

Comment: The sentence is perfectly grammatical by itself. It is in the "[present continuous conditional](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/present-continuous-conditional/)" tense. The conditional itself ("if clause") does not need to be part of the same sentence.

Comment: @TypeIA Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: Also worth noting it could be an answer to a question:
"What would you be doing if you didn't have to work next week?"
"I would be going on a vacation."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but only in a specific context.

"Would" is the *past tense* of the verb *will*. That would make your sentence incorrect, because "*be going*" is future tense.

However, "would" can also be used to indicate the consequence of an imagined event or situation, so it *can* be future-looking but only if you include a condition, for example:

> I *would* be going on a vacation *if only I had a passport*.

If that isn't your intention, then your sentence is incorrect and you probably mean to say:

> I *will* be going on a vacation.

or even

> I *am* going on a vacation.